# MSVC refuses to compile `auto` argument in template class

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++17

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    A& operator/=(const auto&x) { return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    a /= 10;
}
```

It compiles fine on gcc, not on MSVC. Is it a MSVC bug ?
If I replace `auto` by a `template<typename U>`, it works on both compilers.

Comment: `operator/=(const auto&x)` only works since C++20.  Did you enable `/std:c++latest` in your compiler options?

Comment: Yes, MSVC (2019 Community) refuses to compile in C++20. I tried godbolt and gcc compiled it, I don't know if it was C++20.

Comment: IIRC, gcc has an extension that's been around since C++14 that allows the code to compile.  If you add the `-pedantic-errors` flag, it stops it from compiling: https://godbolt.org/z/PWqj4eeYa

Comment: So this is, in fact, illegal?

Comment: It is illegal before C++20.  If you are compiling with C++20, then it should be fine.  Looks like it will compile with the latest version of MSVC when specifying C++20 here: https://godbolt.org/z/vYvPozcEa

Comment: Ok, so I will update my msvc version, thank you.

Comment: If you try MSVC VS16.11 on godbolt (penultimate MSVC option), it fails also on godbolt, so was probably a bug in previous MSVC version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great place where you can use [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/).

clang/LLVM v12 and GCC 12 don't like it either with default compiler options.

The latest version of Visual C++ *can* compile it, but only if you enable `/std:c++20`.

Comment: Can't reproduce, both GCC and Clang do compile it for me. Did you add `-std=c++20`?

Comment: It works on gcc 11.2 with `-std=c++20`: https://godbolt.org/z/9d18f67sa